# Firebase something went wrong flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to create a login page with Firebase but the problem is that when I put my email + my password I have this message that appears:

```
W/System (30113): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(30113): Notifying id token listeners about user ( gZ4NEwxh0qRRl32ypTGvqgX6kJx2 ).
```

I connected Firebase to my application and I put the authentication by mail, I added the sha1 and the sha-256.

Comment: That last message actually looks good, and means that your user was signed in with Firebase. What isn't working? Can you show the [minimal code with which any of us can reproduce that?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with that. Most importantly, you can log into your account.

If you think `Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.` should be removed, I suggest you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73655177/16124033):

> **PREPARATION**
>
> 1. Check if your emulator has the permission to access internet and also is connected to.
> 2. Email/Password Sign-in method in your `firebase` console is enabled to gain access.
>
> **STEP 1:** Create sha1 key + debug key information + Adding `firebase`. You probably have your sha1 key only with the normal
> information from the release key, I guess?
>
> **STEP 2:** Activate Android Device Verification from `console.cloud.google.com` and insert your sha keys that are
> automatically generated by `firebase` + their matching preferences
> (like `package name`...)
>
> **CONCLUSION**
>
> Your code looks good to me! Everything is set up right. I think you
> forgot some trivial settings or the right sha key.

Comment: My terminal was like that: W/System  (32468): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  (32468): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(32468): Notifying id token listeners about user ( vuQMYKu68EXwQPn44lUutVr50Bo1 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(32468): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( vuQMYKu68EXwQPn44lUutVr50Bo1 ).
I/flutter (32468): 122
D/FirebaseAuth(32468): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth(32468): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
I